# TortoiseHg files shown in merge

Tags: mercurial, merge, tortoisehg

I am writing code to do analysis of our commits to `Hg`, and am comparing my results to `TortoiseHg`.  I am having trouble understanding the behavior of `TortoiseHg` in the case of a merge.

When I select a merge changeset in `TortoiseHg`, the list of affected files only shows those files that had conflicts, unless I press the `"Show All"` button.  At least that appears to be the intent, based on what I can glean from the web, and from observation that the files shown in the list have a double headed arrow if I press the Show All button.

I am attempting to emulate that by diffing each file in the changeset against both parents, and only including the file in my analysis if it differs from both parents.  However, I am encountering files that TortoiseHg shows in the description of a merge, but that only differ from one parent.  I see that in `TortoiseHg` as well - diffing against parent 1 or 2 shows a change, but the other parent doesn't.

I have also tried diffing with the `--git` option, to make sure it is not a metadata change I am missing, but that doesn't change the results at all.

To get the information about a changeset I am using:

```
hg log -v -r <rev> --removed --style xml
```

I pick up the parents of the merge changeset, and for each file in the merge, do

```
hg diff -r <parent1> -r <rev> filename
hg diff -r <parent2> -r <rev< filename
```

And I find that files `TortoiseHg` shows in its summary of the merge I report as having merged with no conflicts.

Can anyone shed light on the discrepancy?

Update:
I was able to reproduce this with the source code for TortoiseHg itself.

Clone from https://hg01.codeplex.com/tortoisehg
Open the repo in tortoiseHg and select rev 12602 (58eb7c70).  This is a merge with parents of 12599 (6c716caa) and 12601 (39c95a81).

TortoiseHg shows the file tortoisehg/hgqt/repowidget.py as the only conflicted file in the merge, yet

```
hg diff -r 12599 -r 12602 tortoisehg/hgqt/repowidget.py
```

returns nothing, while

```
hg diff -r 12601 -r 12602 tortoisehg/hgqt/repowidget.py
```

shows two lines changing.

Comment: Is your repository public? Having some real data to look at would make this much easier.

Comment: Sadly no, but I will see if I can recreate the issue on a public repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've figured out what tortoisehg's logic is here (though I haven't checked the source to be sure).

As you've guessed, tortoise shows files changed on both sides of a merge with a double arrow. However, it does not look simply at the diff of the merge to each of its parents (e.g. `p1(58eb7c70)::58eb7c70` and `p2(58eb7c70)::58eb7c70`). Instead, tortoise finds all changes introduced in the merge, compared the last common ancestor of the two parents.

Let's take the tortoise repo as an example. The graph view of the ancestry of 58eb7c70 is:

```
Jonathan:tortoisehg $ hg log --graph -r ::58eb7c70 -l 5 --template "{node|short}\n{desc|firstline}\n\n"
o    58eb7c70d501
|\   Merge with stable (noop)
| |
| o  39c95a813105
| |  repowidget: show all errors on infobar
| |
| o  da7ff15b4b96
| |  repowidget: limit infobar error messages to 2 lines of up to 140 chars by default
| |
o |  6c716caa11fd
|\|  Merge with stable
| |
| o  48c055ad634f
| |  sync: show non-ascii command-line arguments correctly
| |
```

As you can see, merge 58eb7c70d501 merged two branches of development, with one changeset (p1, 6c716caa11fd) on one side, but *two* on the other (p2, 39c95a813105, and its parent, da7ff15b4b96). The point where these branches diverged is the last common ancestor of p1 and p2 -- 48c055ad634f.

(The last common ancestor can be found directly with `hg log -r "last(ancestor(p1(58eb7c70), p2(58eb7c70)))"`)

Let's look at the changes that were made on those two branches. We'll compare each parent of the merge with the common ancestor:

```
Jonathan:tortoisehg $ hg status --rev "48c055ad634f::6c716caa11fd"
M .hgtags
M tortoisehg/hgqt/commit.py
M tortoisehg/hgqt/compress.py
M tortoisehg/hgqt/hgemail.py
M tortoisehg/hgqt/postreview.py
M tortoisehg/hgqt/purge.py
M tortoisehg/hgqt/rename.py
M tortoisehg/hgqt/repowidget.py
M tortoisehg/hgqt/revset.py
M tortoisehg/hgqt/run.py
M tortoisehg/hgqt/settings.py
M tortoisehg/hgqt/status.py
M tortoisehg/hgqt/sync.py
M tortoisehg/hgqt/visdiff.py
M tortoisehg/util/cachethg.py
M tortoisehg/util/hglib.py

Jonathan:tortoisehg $ hg status --rev "48c055ad634f::39c95a813105"
M tortoisehg/hgqt/repowidget.py
```

These are the changes that were actually merged by 58eb7c70d501 -- everything changed on the two branches since they diverged. As you can see, the only file in common between the lists -- the only file that was changed on both branches -- is `tortoisehg/hgqt/repowidget.py`, just as you expected. You'll see that this file was changed in da7ff15b4b96, the one changeset that's not a parent of the merge but is still included in the changes merged from the two branches.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  Thank you so much for the in-depth analysis.  And now I know how to recreate that logic in my own code.  Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`tortoisehg/hgqt/repowidget.py` was modified in [6c716caa11fd](https://hg01.codeplex.com/tortoisehg/rev/6c716caa11fd), which would explain why your second call to `hg diff` gives you results; the first call compares two revisions across which no changes were registered to `tortoisehg/hgqt/repowidget.py`; this seems sound to me, unless I am missing something else about how `hg diff` behaves.

Comment: The behavior of diff makes sense to me.  What I am trying to figure out is why tortoise flags this file as having changes on each side of the merge (i.e. conflicts).  I am mostly interested in trying to replicate the behavior of tortoise so that the analysis I do on our commits and merges will give the same answers as tortoise.  Just based on the diffs I would say that file merged without conflicts.